# Python |S1 vector to string

Tags: python-3.x, string, dtype

i have a vector "char" of type |S1 like in the example below:

```
masked_array(data=[b'E', b'U', b'3', b'7', b'6', b'8', b' ', b' ', b' ', b' '],
             mask=False,
       fill_value=b'N/A',
            dtype='|S1')
```

I want to get the string in it, in this example 'EU3768'

This example is taken from a netcdf file. Library used is netCDF4.

Further question: Why is there a b in front of all single letters?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all let's answer the most basic question: What is the meaning of the b in front of each letter.  The b simply indicates that the character string is in bytes.  The internal format of the data is being stored encoded as utf-8.  So to convert it back to a string it must be decoded.  So with that as a preamble, the following code will do the trick.

I am assuming that you can extract data from the masked_array. Then perform the following operations:

```
#  Convert the list of bytes to a list of strings
ds = list(map(lambda x: x.decode('utf-8'), data))

#  Covert List of strings to a String and strip any trailing spaces
sd = ''.join(ds).strip()
```

This could of course be performed in a single line of code as follows:

```
sd = ''.join(list(map(lambda x: x.decode('utf-8'), data))).strip()
```

Comment: You don't need to convert the `map(...)` to a `list`. `map(...)` creates a [generator expression](https://jpt-pynotes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generators-comprehensions.html) that can be taken by `join()`

Comment: Or if you're like me and feel generator expressions are more intuitive than a lambda, `sd = ''.join(x.decode('utf-8') for x in data).strip()`

Comment: good point https://stackoverflow.com/users/843953/pranav-hosangadi, i was just trying to layout the solution in steps and didn't think it all the way through.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a bit, now i understand what this 'b' means. I also am able now to make a string out of a single vector 'char'. But now i have another problem: In my file are about 100.000 of those vectors each with 10 entries building a string each. Shape of the data is (100.000,10). So in the end there should be 100.000 strings. This method works, but it is incredible slow that it is not really an option. Is there a way to do this for all 100.000 vectors in a very short amount of time, so without using any loop?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by a long time, since the conversion of a list to a string takes O(n) time where n = length of list, I can't imagine there being a  quicker way to perform the operation.  I haven't attempted to time the operation, but if each translation takes about 100 usecs, you are still translating all 100,000 in about 10 secs.

Comment: Yes, for the real dataset it's a bit more then 20 seconds. But this is far too much, there must be a faster way, maybe with another method or package. I have more then 10.000 of such files. This is more then 2 days only for converting this binary strings .. .. there is always a better and faster solution, but i'm quiet new to python and don't know all libraries and methods. And loops are always a very bad idea, there must be a way doing it just by indices.

Comment: I doubt you will find anything that works in less than O(n) time.  Good luck

Comment: I don't know what computer you are running on, but 1 million translations takes about 2.8 seconds when timed with timeit. If your process is taking much longer than that, the bottleneck may not be in the translation function but in the load function.

Answer (score 1):

as an answer to your follow-up question, you might be able to let Numpy do some of the work by just working with the underlying bytes.  for example, I can create a large number of similar shaped objects via:

```
import numpy as np
from string import ascii_letters, digits

letters = np.array(list(ascii_letters + digits), dtype='S1')

v = np.random.choice(letters, (100_000, 10))
```

The first three elements of this look like:

```
[[b'W' b'B' b'W' b'4' b'O' b'B' b'A' b'4' b'Q' b'n']
 [b'I' b'I' b'T' b'u' b'K' b'K' b'U' b'a' b'r' b'r']
 [b'V' b'f' b'n' b'U' b'G' b'0' b'j' b'R' b'm' b'C']]
```

I can then convert these back to strings via some byte level shanigans:

```
[bytes.decode(s) for s in np.frombuffer(v, dtype='S10')]
```

The first three look like:

```
['WBW4OBA4Qn', 'IITuKKUarr', 'VfnUG0jRmC']
```

which hopefully makes sense.  This takes ~20ms which is quicker than a version which goes through Python:

```
[b''.join(r).decode() for r in v]
```

taking ~200ms.  This is still much faster than the version of code you posted, so maybe you could be accessing netcdf more efficiently.